# PHPExcel download file, excel file hieroglyphics

Tags: php, encoding, download, phpexcel

i have a problem to download excel file. When im saving on server its worked ok. But when i try to download things goes wrong.This is my code:

```
$result = getSoapResult($soapURL, $soapWSDL, $soapMETHOD, $inputParameters);
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="file_name.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$rowCount = 1;

$column = 'A';
foreach($result as $key => $value){
        if($rowCount == 1){
            foreach($value as $k => $v){
                $objExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column.$rowCount, $k);
                $column++;
            }
            $rowCount++;
        }
        $column = 'A';
        foreach($value as $k => $v){
            $objExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column.$rowCount, $v);
            $column++;
        }
    $rowCount++;
}

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

it gives an excel file with this content:

[image]

I cant find answer from another questions with this problem.

Comment: Try removing the headers and see what is outputted. It could be spitting errors at you, but interpreting it as excel because you forced it to.

Comment: Open the file in a text editor. Look for leading/trailing whitespace characters; BOM header; or any plaintext messages in the body of the file

Comment: I remove the headers, same thing in browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PK at the begining gives away it's a `zip` file. Coincidentally, `xlsx` is a special kind of `zip` file. Try to save the file as `.xlsx` instead of `.xls` and Excel should handle it correctly.

Given you're specifying `Excel2007` as the format, you're getting an `.xlsx` file. If you need a `.xls` file, maybe you can use `Excel2003` instead.

Comment: Well noticed, I'd missed that; and the `charset=utf-8` in the `Content-Type` is totally meaningless as well; the charset for an Excel file is part of the file content itself

Comment: One more problem, when i save and open file its ok, but when i directly open with Excel its like the previous, with hieroglyphics.

Comment: When opens its save like filename.xlsx.xls

Answer (score 0):

Please add the code before your file download code

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
```